# Can I multiply Big-O time complexities?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

Can I multiply Big-O time complexities?

For example: $O(n) \cdot O(n) = O(n^2)$?

UPDATE:

The question came from my observation that different sources analyze their algorithms in different ways. For example, some use the following $O(n \cdot n +  n \cdot log (n) )$ notation and some more like $O(n) \cdot O(n) + O(n) \cdot O(log (n))$ notation. I was wondering if it is equivalent notations.

Comment: $O(n)$ is a set of functions. Do you mean set product here?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami if I got your question correctly, then yes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can  and yes, it is.

Considering, for example, the non-negative case, we have a more general property:
$$O(f)\cdot O(g) = O(f\cdot g )$$
Let's take $ \varphi \in O(f) \cdot O(g) $. Then we have $\varphi = \varphi_{1} \cdot \varphi_{2}$ where
$$\exists C_{1} > 0, \exists N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n  >  N_{1},\   \varphi_{1} \leqslant C_{1} \cdot f $$
$$\exists C_{2} > 0, \exists N_{2} \in \mathbb{N},\ \forall n  >  N_{2},\   \varphi_{2} \leqslant C_{2} \cdot g $$
From above $\varphi = \varphi_{1} \cdot \varphi_{2} \leqslant C_{1} \cdot f \cdot C_{2} \cdot g = C_{1} \cdot C_{2} \cdot  f \cdot  g $ when $ n>N=max(N_{1},N_{2}) $.

Accordingly, we can also see that there is a second general property:
$$O(f)+O(g) = O(f+ g )$$
The proof uses the same technique.

**Definitions:**
$$O(f)\cdot O(g) = \left\lbrace a\cdot  b \colon (a,b)\in O(f)\times O(g)  \right\rbrace $$
$$O(f)+O(g) = \left\lbrace a + b \colon (a,b)\in O(f)\times O(g)  \right\rbrace $$

Comment: Hi zkutch. If I am understanding it correctly, you proved that if $ \varphi \in O(f) \cdot O(g) $ then $ \varphi \in O(f \cdot g)$. We might need to prove the vice-versa statement also, i.e., if $ \varphi \in O(f \cdot g)$ then $ \varphi \in O(f) \cdot O(g) $?

Comment: Yes, @Inuyasha Yagami. You are correct and I am very glad, that at last meet correctly seen situation, though many well known resources counts enough so called "one-way" direction. Of course, imo, equality of sets needs reverse inclusion, but let me suggest firstly wait OP reaction on brought. Proof of reverse direction is slightly more tricky, but also interesting.

Comment: @zkutch Thank you for your answer. I just added an additional clarification to my question and want to confirm that different notations are equivalent.

Comment: @illuminato. Wrote addition. Write, please, if/when something needs more clearing.

Comment: What's the definition of $O(f) \cdot O(g)$ that you are using? Is $O(f) \cdot O(g) = \{ f_i \cdot g_j \mid f_i \in O(f), g_j \in O(g)\}$?

Comment: @Bakuriu. I added definitions to answer.

Comment: If you think that proofs of equality of sets requires two inclusions, why settle for just one? The fact that OP is satisfied with half a proof doesn't mean that you need to be.

Comment: Because it is answer to question @John Coleman. Please note that the questioner does not ask for proof, the question is about the validity of using certain notations. I showed a technique that allows you to restore the missing 3/4 parts yourself. Also, let me say that sometimes adding a lot of details complicates the answer, making it cumbersome and difficult to understand. If you, or anyone else, are interested in the proofs, then just write about it, perhaps better in a new question, so as not to clutter up this one, and I will answer with pleasure.

Comment: O-notation equalities are often meant to read only left-to-right inclusion anyway. Like $n^2+3 = O(n^2) = O(n^3)$ is often (ab)used form of writing $n^2+3 \in O(n^2) \subset O(n^3)$

Comment: Agree,  @RiaD. This is why I think it's it's long overdue  to stop using $O(n^2)=O(n^3)$ and write formally correct $O(n^2)\subset O(n^3)$. If we have defined something as a set, then let's behave with it accordingly.

Comment: I think this ship has sailed :)

Comment: (just noticed you are an author of the answer) Actually my argument was why it makes sense for your post to not contain proof in the other direction. If you prefer the notation with sets, then my argument doesn't make sense and it makes sense to actually prove the fact in both directions

Comment: @RiaD. Read, please, my thoughts on this in the comment in response to the comment of John Coleman above. Do you think it need to be added here or somewhere separately? There are two more halves also for addition.

Comment: Also note that this does not extend to powers.  O(f)^O(g) is not O(f^g) for the natural definition of O(f)^O(g).  Examine O(2^n) and O(2^(2n)) and O(3^n) vs O(2^(n+2)); O notation isn't quite "loose" enough to deal with powers well.

Comment: I blurred more over division @Yakk, but the degree, of course, is also interesting. Only I did not quite understand - what is in your example $f$ and what is $g$? Maybe it is worth analyzing this moment in a separate question.

Answer (score 12):

It's an abuse of notation.

$O(n)$ is a set of functions.

So $O(n)*O(n)$ is not really defined.  $O(n)\times O(n)$ is defined, but it is defined as cartesian products of the set of functions in $O(n)$ by itself.  This is probably not what you are after.

Within the context of algorithm analysis most would interpret $O(f)*O(g)$ to mean that we do some operation a number of time bounded by $f$, and each operation takes relevant resource (e.g. time or space) bounded by $g$.  By that interpretation $O(f)*O(g)\subset O(f*g)$

Comment: For numbers, or functions of numbers, one can define $A\cdot B=\{a\cdot b\mid \forall a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: @nirshahar Sure.  It's just not how I would read $O(f)*O(g)$ in a paper about algorithm complexity.

Comment: Yea, I agree that the specifics of the definition aren't that important. Just the fact we know what it means :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So would you recommend using e.g. $O(n \cdot n +  n \cdot log (n) )$ notation instead of $O(n) \cdot O(n) + O(n) \cdot O(log (n))$ when analyzing time complexities?

Comment: @illuminato Very very definitely.

Comment: @illuminato I would recommend $O(n^2)$ as the conclusion, and both your notations only as intermediary steps.  But those intermediary steps should be accompanied with enough text that it is clear what you mean.

Comment: Bachmann-Landau notation is inherently an abuse of notation.