# How do I use the definition of the "Big-Oh" notation to prove the following statements?

Tags: complexity-theory

I need help figuring out how to prove the following statement using the definition of "Big-Oh" notation which says that `f ~ g if there are constants C and n_0 such that f(n) <= C*g(n), for n >= n_0`. I have down below shared my attempts but am quite unsure about everything. For all I know I am not doing this correctly.

**Statement 1:**
`If f(n) ∈ O(f'(n)) and g(n) ∈ O(g'(n)), then f(n)g(n) ∈ O(f'(n)g'(n))`

I can start by qouting the definition. We want to prove that `f(n)g(n) ∈ O(f'(n)g'(n))` which means that `f(n)g(n) <= Cj(n) ∀ n ≥ n_0` where `j(n) is the order of growth` is true for some constants `C` and `n_0`.

We are given that `f(n) ∈ O(f'(n)) => f(n) <= C_1 * f'(n)` and that `g(n) ∈ O(g'(n)) => g(n) <= C_2 * g'(n)`. Using this information it must be true that `f(n)g(n) <= C_1*f'(n) * C_2*g'(n) = Cf'(n)g'(n) => f(n)g(n) ∈ O(f'(n)g'(n))`. Have I proven **statement 1**?

Comment: Does this help https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143567/can-i-multiply-big-o-time-complexities/143572#143572 ?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.